# Do any altcoins use a DHT for connecting to peers?

Tags: altcoin, protocol, network

[Bitcoin doesn't use a DHT for connecting to peers.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37366/4334) Are there any altcoins that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Both Eth(https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Kademlia-Peer-Selection) and Ada(https://cardanodocs.com/technical/protocols/p2p/) use Kademlia DHT.